# Java synchronized keyword doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, synchronized

My requirement is to fetch a code from the table in the database and mark it as deleted so that it is never fetched again. We noticed that twice the same code was being fetched. So, I synchronized the method as below:

```
public synchronized String fetchCode(School school) {

log.info("fetching code for school id : {}", school.getId());
//DB query to fetch the code (For a certain school id, there can be many codes and we need to use one at a time and delete it)
log.info("fetched code : {}", code);
//DB query to mark the code as deleted
return code;
}
```

While debugging, I notice that the logs print the first log twice consecutively and then the second log. And the code was the same in both the logs. So, it seems the synchronized keyword is not doing any good. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of whatever class this method is defined on?

Comment: From the docs: `First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave.` So my guess is there's a second object?

Comment: Yes, there are two objects which are invoking the method. So a Kafka topic picks a message and based on the message does this. When two messages come back to back quickly, we face this issue.

Comment: @Beko Can you please suggest how do I achieve what I want to do here ?

Comment: You need to synchronize on one object.

Comment: I don't know tbh. Perhaps provide a little more code, e.g. where the method gets called. A boolean flag may help.

Comment: I think I was wrong. We are using Spring and the object of this class is auto wired in the calling class. By default, Spring creates a singleton object so then, it must be the same object, not different.

Comment: I too would expect Spring to create only one instance, but I trust the JVM to implement `synchronized` correctly more than I trust Spring. Include `System.identityHashCode(this)` in the log output to make sure you have the same object.

Comment: You are right. I logged the hashcode and both the threads have different ones. i am using contructor injection in the calling class so, I am not sure why this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to touch the Kafka parts of this since as great as what that project has produced with respect to streaming may be, synchronization simply must be done, and synchronization is never easy--no matter what parallelization fetishists try to sell to you.

If you want to do this correctly, then move the semaphore locking as close to the data as you can.  When you fetch the record(s) to be marked deleted from the database, use the `for update` qualifier.  This will lock those records in the DBMS and block any other processes from issuing `select...for update` on those same records.  It will also block any other processes issuing an `update` or `delete` on those records.

Documentation and examples of specifying locks on `select` can be found in the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE).

Comment: Could you please provide a link to any article where I can find more about the 'for update' strategy that you mention?

Comment: @TAnna Added a link to the docs covering locking on `select`.